# Swift Class Property Not Recognized in Extension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, class, methods

This has been tripping me up for some time now. I am trying to dequeue a list into a table view (embedded in a view controller).

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {
    var topicsE1: [Topic] = [
        Topic(title: "Practice", startDate: "January 5, 2019"),
        Topic(title: "Fundamentals", startDate: "January 6, 2019")]
```

The extension:

```
extension mainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topicCellE1", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(topicsE1.title)" //Error message is here
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return topicsE1.count
    }
}
```

The class is defined in another file

```
class Topic {
    var title: String
    var startDate: String

    init(title: String, startDate: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.startDate = startDate
    }
}
```

The extension recognized topicsE1, but gives the error

> "Value of type '[Topic]' has no member 'title'"

when the code is as above (topicsE1.title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
cell.textLabel?.text = topicsE1[indexPath.row].title
```

as `topicsE1` is an array that you can't append `.title`  directly to it